# Cross platform/machine way of defining qmake build configuration

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, qmake

We use *qmake* (with Qt Creator) for building our C++ App. Now we want to have multiple build configurations, which are platform/machine independent.

The build configuration is added to the `mypro.pro.user` file. We want the configurations to be available on all platforms/machines (via adding to VCS). Adding the `pro.user` file to the VCS is not an option. Is there any other way of adding a build configuration to the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can add config to *.pro file:

```
myconfig1 {
#yourconfig1
}
myconfig2 {
#yourconfig2
}
```

And in qmake command line add:

> CONFIG+=myconfig1

Comment: I want multiple build configurations to switch from. The command line is no good when using Qt Creator.